# Converting int to string still works even when causing buffer overflow

Tags: c, string, int

I'm trying to convert `int` to a C-string using this code:

```
static char* copyString(const char* str)  
{
    char* new_String = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    return strcpy(new_String, str);
}
static char* mallocIntToString(const int num)
{
    char s[10]; // *************
    sprintf(s, "%d", num);
    char* copy = copyString(s);

    return copy;
}
```

I was wandering what is the biggest number I should insert in the line 
`char s[10];`.

I used 10 because its the max digits for an integer. However, this code also works for me when I use `char s[9];`, trying to convert the number 2147483647 to string, how is it possible?

Comment: Look at `<limits.h>`.  For example, `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` may be defined as `-2147483648` and `+2147483647`, respectively.

Comment: Both are wrong and the code just happens to work. A 10-digit number requires 11 chars, because there must be space for the terminating `'\0'`. Even so, you will run into trouble with −2147483648, where you need one extra char for the sign.

Comment: Undefined Behavior Is Undefined. Anything could happen, including "working" today and breaking next week.

Comment: FYI: there's already `strdup` that does exactly what your `copyString` function is doing (and with proper error checking).

Comment: Why bother with copying the resulting string at all? Just allocate an appropriately sized buffer on the heap and use `sprintf()` to write the result into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wandering what is the biggest number I should insert in the line `char s[10];`.

You should insert the maximum length between `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` defined in `<limits.h>`. `INT_MIN` should be `-2147483648`, so you need 11 + 1 = 12 characters (the additional one is for the string terminator `\0`).

A correct implementation would be:

```
static char* mallocIntToString(const int num)
{
    char *s;

    s = malloc(12);
    if (s == NULL)
        return NULL;

    sprintf(s, "%d", num);    
    // Should probably also check for error here.

    return s;
}
```

> However, this code also works for me when I use `char s[9];`, trying to convert the number `2147483647` to string, how is it possible?

You're invoking undefined behavior, since writing past the end of an array is undefined behavior. When doing so, anything can happen. The program is not guaranteed to work correctly, but *out of pure coincidence*, it could still *seem to work*. What is happening in your code is that since the variable is defined on the stack, and the stack is writable, writing one or two bytes more does not change much because the program is still writing to valid memory. With that being said, it's still undefined behavior and should be avoided at all costs!

To be 100% clear, you would be invoking undefined behavior even with `char s[10];` or `char s[11];`, because in the case of `INT_MIN` the terminator would be written out of the array bounds.

Comment: hey Marco, thank you for your very detailed answer, you made it absolutely clear for me :)

Comment: @NivBehar you're welcome. If I answered your question you can accept my answer with the checkmark button on the left so that your post can be marked as solved.